# Coloring the Chess Board

Tags: logical-deduction, optimization

We have 8x8 Chess board like grid (8x8 2D matrix) and we are trying to color every single square/cell. But the rules are interesting;

- You may start from any square you want and color that square for the beginning.
- You can continue coloring another square in the grid which is $4$ or $5$ squares away from the square you started and colored from and so on (vertically or horizontally).
- You cannot color the same square you colored before or come back again on that.

[image]

> What is **the maximum amount of squares** you can color with the given rule above?

Comment: Am I right in thinking this is an 8 x 8 x 8 cube? I think that may need to be included in the question if so

Comment: @AHKieran this is 8x8 Grid, not a cube. what makes you think like that? Oo

Comment: sorry i meant an 8 x 8 x A cuboid, so the grids are extruded upwards A times?

Comment: perhaps some sort of diagram example would be useful?

Comment: Oray, you are misusing the word "Grid". Grid refers to the whole array of squares, whereas you seem to be using it to refer to a single square.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis yeah, you are right, that's on me:)

Comment: @AHKieran is it clear now?

Comment: Can you go over a colored square? (For example, with a3 colored, can you go from a1 to a5?)

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu you can, fixed the explanation.

Comment: yes that's better, the concept of multiple grids is what confused me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The one-dimensional problem can be solved as follows:

> |2|4|6|8|1|3|5|7|
>
>  Since we start and end at a central square, we can use the same strategy on the Y-axis and colour one row at a time. In the end we'll have coloured all 64 squares.

Using chessboard coordinates:

> e5 a5 f5 b5 g5 c5 h5 d5
>  d1 h1 c1 g1 b1 f1 a1 e1
>  e6 a6 f6 b6 g6 c6 h6 d6
>  d2 h2 c2 g2 b2 f2 a2 e2
>  e7 a7 f7 b7 g7 c7 h7 d7
>  d3 h3 c3 g3 b3 f3 a3 e3
>  e8 a8 f8 b8 g8 c8 h8 d8
>  d4 h4 c4 g4 b4 f4 a4 e4

Comment: Er... you can't cross squares that have already been colored.

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu Yes you can. Oray at first misread your question in the comments, but then corrected himself a minute or so later.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis ah, I definitely didn't see the edit, I was busy typing my answer (with no crossing)

Comment: @jafe This is a lovely solution. I was trying to go around in 4x4 squares, filling two rows simultaneously, but was always left with two or more unreachable squares.

Comment: So the answer is "64". You answer implies that you're gunning for 64, but, I think you should actually say 64.

Comment: @StephenQuan Reworded to include the number.

Answer (score 3):

I think I can get:

> 63 out of 64 squares coloured

Method:

> You start in one of the centre lines, 4 in from the left, and move left 4, right 5, left 4, right 5 etc until the whole line is filled.
>  Then you repeat this vertically, starting from the square you last filled in the row, until the whole column is filled.
>  Repeating this ends up with a cross in middle 2 rows/columns. After this, repeating this line filling method creates a window like shape with the outside squares also filled.
>  At this point I managed to go around and fill the inner squares, but I could not move from the last one I filled to the the one remaining square so ended on 63.

Answer (score 0):

I can do

> 17, without even crossing a colored square

by

> using chessboard coordinates,  e4 - e8 - a8 - a3 - f3 - f7 - b7 - b2 - g2 - g6 - c6 - c1 - h1 - h5 - d5 - d1

Answer (score 0):

All 64;

> order is as follows:
>
> [02,04,06,08,10,12,14,16]
>
> [32,30,28,26,24,22,20,18]
>
> [34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48]
>
> [64,62,60,58,56,54,52,50]
>
> [01,03,05,07,09,11,13,15]
>
> [31,29,27,25,23,21,19,17]
>
> [33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47]
>
> [63,61,59,57,55,53,51,49]

sorry about the formatting