# Coloring the Chess Board v2

Tags: logical-deduction

This is a follow up question to [Coloring the Chess Board](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/76045/coloring-the-chess-board)

> We have 8x8 Chess board like grid (8x8 2D matrix) and we are trying to
>   color every single square/cell. But the rules are interesting;
>
> - <s>You may start from any square you want</s> and color that square for the beginning.
> - You can continue coloring another square in the grid which is $4$ or $5$ squares away from the square you started and colored from and so
>     on (vertically or horizontally).
> - You cannot color the same square you colored before or come back again on that.
>
> [image]

This time, you are *not allowed to start from any square you want*; you need to start from a corner square (in other words, in chess language a1,a8,h1,h8).

so

> What is **the maximum amount of squares** you can color with the given rule above now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get

> 64

Like this:

> Fill everything except file e and ranks 4-5.
>  a1 a6 a2 a7 a3 a8
>  f8 f3 f7 f2 f6 f1
>  b1 b6 b2 b7 b3 b8
>  g8 g3 g7 g2 g6 g1
>  c1 c6 c2 c7 c3 c8
>  h8 h3 h7 h2 h6 h1
>  d1 d6 d2 d7 d3 d8
>
>  Fill rank 4
>  d4 h4 c4 g4 b4 f4 a4 e4
>
>  Fill the e-file
>  e8 e3 e7 e2 e6 e1 e5
>
>  Fill the rest of rank 5
>  a5 f5 b5 g5 c5 h5 d5

Comment: so we dont have to start in the middle :)